# Extract List of Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, boto3

I have the following list:

```
    {
   "TargetHealthDescriptions":[
      {
         "Target":{
            "Id":"10.101.100.101",
            "Port":8200,
            "AvailabilityZone":"all"
         },
         "HealthCheckPort":"8200",
         "TargetHealth":{
            "State":"healthy"
         }
      },
      {
         "Target":{
            "Id":"10.102.100.102",
            "Port":8200,
            "AvailabilityZone":"all"
         },
         "HealthCheckPort":"8200",
         "TargetHealth":{
            "State":"healthy"
         }
      },
      {
         "Target":{
            "Id":"10.103.100.103",
            "Port":8200,
            "AvailabilityZone":"all"
         },
         "HealthCheckPort":"8200",
         "TargetHealth":{
            "State":"healthy"
         }
      }
   ],
   "ResponseMetadata":{
      "RequestId":"abcdef-01234-4d84-9aaf-0123456789",
      "HTTPStatusCode":200,
      "HTTPHeaders":{
         "x-amzn-requestid":"870c5177-482b-4d84-9aaf-0123456789",
         "content-type":"text/xml",
         "content-length":"1279",
         "date":"Mon, 11 Jul 2022 15:35:38 GMT"
      },
      "RetryAttempts":0
   }
}
```

How can I extract each target Id? I basically need to extract update these IPs if a dig command does not match. So far the only thing I have been able to do is print ['TargetHealthDescriptions'][0] but whenever I try iterate over the list I get a "<generator object  at 0x10522c890>" so not sure what that even means.

Comment: That's not a list, it's a dictionary.

Comment: Please show the code that gives you this output. [Ask]

Comment: you are right @Barmar I apologize 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to identify and iterate over the list from within the dictionary by using it's key.  The key in this dictionary is `the_response['TargetHealthDescriptions']`.

Once you have that you can then iterate over it like any other list treating each result as a dictionary, getting the value within it you require, which in this case is `['Target']['Id']` so it looks like this:

```
for target in the_response['TargetHealthDescriptions']:
    print(target['Target']['Id'])
```

Minimal example below:

```
the_response =     {
   "TargetHealthDescriptions":[
      {
         "Target":{
            "Id":"10.101.100.101",
            "Port":8200,
            "AvailabilityZone":"all"
         },
         "HealthCheckPort":"8200",
         "TargetHealth":{
            "State":"healthy"
         }
      },
      {
         "Target":{
            "Id":"10.102.100.102",
            "Port":8200,
            "AvailabilityZone":"all"
         },
         "HealthCheckPort":"8200",
         "TargetHealth":{
            "State":"healthy"
         }
      },
      {
         "Target":{
            "Id":"10.103.100.103",
            "Port":8200,
            "AvailabilityZone":"all"
         },
         "HealthCheckPort":"8200",
         "TargetHealth":{
            "State":"healthy"
         }
      }
   ],
   "ResponseMetadata":{
      "RequestId":"abcdef-01234-4d84-9aaf-0123456789",
      "HTTPStatusCode":200,
      "HTTPHeaders":{
         "x-amzn-requestid":"870c5177-482b-4d84-9aaf-0123456789",
         "content-type":"text/xml",
         "content-length":"1279",
         "date":"Mon, 11 Jul 2022 15:35:38 GMT"
      },
      "RetryAttempts":0
   }
}

for target in the_response['TargetHealthDescriptions']:
    print(target['Target']['Id'])
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @Johnny I really appreciate the explanation on this 

Answer (score 2):

```
for description in data['TargetHealthDescriptions']:
    print(description['Target']['Id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the list in the `TargetHealthDescriptions` element of the dictionary.

```
for thd in obj['TargetHealthDescriptions']:
    id = thd['Target']['Id']
    if dig_does_not_match(id):
        thd['Target']['Id'] = something_else
```

Answer (score 0):

A generator object just means the list is being lazily fetched. You can wrap the generator with the `list` class to convert it to a list:

```
descs = list(obj['TargetHealthDescriptions'])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can define the dataset as a dictionary and iterate through each nested dictionary with for loops. Probably not the most efficient method, but it does get the job done.

Dataset:

```
dict = {
   "TargetHealthDescriptions":[
      {
         "Target":{
            "Id":"10.101.100.101",
            "Port":8200,
            "AvailabilityZone":"all"
         },
         "HealthCheckPort":"8200",
         "TargetHealth":{
            "State":"healthy"
         }
      },
      {
         "Target":{
            "Id":"10.102.100.102",
            "Port":8200,
            "AvailabilityZone":"all"
         },
         "HealthCheckPort":"8200",
         "TargetHealth":{
            "State":"healthy"
         }
      },
      {
         "Target":{
            "Id":"10.103.100.103",
            "Port":8200,
            "AvailabilityZone":"all"
         },
         "HealthCheckPort":"8200",
         "TargetHealth":{
            "State":"healthy"
         }
      }
   ],
   "ResponseMetadata":{
      "RequestId":"abcdef-01234-4d84-9aaf-0123456789",
      "HTTPStatusCode":200,
      "HTTPHeaders":{
         "x-amzn-requestid":"870c5177-482b-4d84-9aaf-0123456789",
         "content-type":"text/xml",
         "content-length":"1279",
         "date":"Mon, 11 Jul 2022 15:35:38 GMT"
      },
      "RetryAttempts":0
   }
}
```

Logic:

```
for x in dict:
    if x == "TargetHealthDescriptions":
       for attr in dict[x]:
          attr_dict = attr
          for y in attr_dict:
             if y == "Target":
                target_dict = attr_dict[y]
                Id = target_dict.get('Id')
                print(Id)
```

Returns:

```
10.101.100.101
10.102.100.102
10.103.100.103
```